# fetch-api in express app with body parser has blank request body if using form object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, body-parser

I'm trying to send a post request with front-end javascript fetch, a form object, and body-parser in an express app.

I can send the data as JSON, but when I try to use a form-object the request body is blank. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

app.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Here is my route:

```
exports.post_endpoint = async(req, res)=>{
    console.log('req.body = ', req.body);
    res.send({        
        test: 'test'
    });
};
```

If I define the data without a form it works:

```
fetch(url, {  
    method: 'post',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN':"MY-CSRF-TOKEN"},
    body: JSON.stringify({ "user": {
      "email" : 'test1',
      "password" : 'test2'
    }}),
})
```

console output: `req.body =  { user: { email: 'test1', password: 'test2' } }`

But when I try to use a form req.body is blank:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

fetch(url, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        ,'X-CSRF-TOKEN':"MY-CSRF-TOKEN"
    },
    body: formData
})
```

console output: `req.body =  {}`

Edit:

Thanks to Quentin the answer was to add `upload.none()` to the route and remove `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` from headers since fetch added that automatically.

in app.js:

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: path.join(__dirname, 'uploads') });
app.post('/endpoint', upload.none(), my_router.post_endpoint);
```

multer `upload.none()` sends the data to `req.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

- `FormData` objects send `multipart/form-data` payloads. You only have body parsing middleware for JSON payloads and URL encoded payloads.
- The `Content-Type` for `multipart/form-data` has a **mandatory** `boundary` parameter which you are omitting (also you have no way to find out what it is so you shouldn't override the `Content-Type` header that `fetch` would otherwise automatically generate from the `FormData` object)

The key benefit of `FormData` is that it supports file attachments. Since you don't have any it ends up bloating your payload size. I'd stick to JSON or use URL Encoding.